# Printing arabic text using xps

Tags: c#, printing, xps

I use XPS printer as my default printer but when I print, the print document (which contains Arabic text) alignment and text is completely disordered.

When a physical printer is used, the result is absolutely correct. Can anyone please suggest what might be wrong?

[image]